# Django and ajax request Method Not Allowed (POST)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am getting Method Not Allowed (POST) when I send an ajax post. It doesn't even get to the first request.method == 'POST' validation.

I already checked everything I could think of and still I cannot figure out the error, probably something ridiculous.
Already tried submitting the form directly through the 'action' attribute pointing to the same url, with the 'POST' method and I get the same error.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

My url:

```
url(r'^crear_familiar/$', familiar_create, name='crear_familiar'),
```

My ajax:

```
var url = "{% url 'crear_familiar' %}";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $("#familiarForm").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data, 'SUCCESS');
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('ERROR', data);
    }
});
```

My view:

```
def familiar_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        familiar_form = FamiliarForm(request.POST, prefix='familiar')
        if familiar_form.is_valid():
            familiar = familiar_form.save(commit=False)

            familiar.save()
            message = 'Has creado un nuevo familiar'
            if request.POST['familiar_familia']:
                familia_id = request.POST['familiar_familia']
                familia = Familia.objects.get(id=familia_id)
                tipo_familiar_id = request.POST['fhf-tipo_familiar']
                tipo_familiar = TipoFamiliar.objects.get(id=tipo_familiar_id)

                familiar_assignment = FamiliaHasFamiliar(
                    familia=familia,
                    familiar=familiar,
                    tipo_familiar=tipo_familiar
                )

                familiar_assignment.save()

                message = 'Has creado un nuevo familiar y le has asignado una familia'
            status = 200

        else:
            message = 'Ocurrió un error al crear al familiar'
            status = 500

        return JsonResponse({'status': 'false', 'message': message},
                            status=status)
    else:
        print 'GET'
        return JsonResponse(
            {'status': 'false', 'message': 'Wrong request'},
            status=500
        )
```

Form:

```
<form id="familiarForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'crear_familiar' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="familiar_familia" value="{{ object.pk }}" hidden>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ familiar_form.nombre.label }}:
                    <span class="text-danger bold">*</span>
                    {{ familiar_form.nombre|add_class:"form-control required" }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ familiar_form.apellidos.label }}:
                    <span class="text-danger bold">*</span>
                    {{ familiar_form.apellidos|add_class:"form-control required" }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button id="saveFamiliar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" familiar_pk="0">
            Submit <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you passing the `csrf` token?

Comment: Yes, I have the django {% csrf_token %} in the form

Comment: Signs point to the url configuration being off. Check that the post url that was used (you can check the network tab in the browser dev console) matches what you need, and try to access the url directly to make sure no other url overrides it.

Comment: Alright. Just checked and both direct access and the network information point to the url I need. Also checked if there were any duplicates, but found nothing amiss.

Comment: is the URL to which the Ajax is sent correct?

Comment: Could you show us the form?

Comment: Ok, I included the form in the question as well. The url seems to be correct. I tried deleting the view to which it points and it threw the right error

Comment: But you haven't shown the right form, please show us the html form `familiarForm`.

Comment: My bad. There it is. But it's basically the same thing, I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the error:
Right before the url that was not working I had another one with a regex:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', FamiliaDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detalle_familia')
```

Looks like this one acted up when I sent the one I actually needed but thought I was sending the wrong arguments/method. I thought it was actually using the one I needed because the request contained the 'correct' text for the url.

The fix was to modify it so the regex did not match any others after it:

```
url(r'^detalle/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', FamiliaDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detalle_familia')
```

Comment: saved my life. So many time for searching an hypothetical and unintentional code error. The "bad" URL took precedence over the good one